# Spring MongoDb BasicQuery equivalent for Aggregations

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I looked through the docs a bit and searched s/o but can’t find anything like BasicQuery for aggregations. I need to be able to pass the actual JSON mongo query to the spring mongo template. Am I thinking about this wrong? Is there a way to pass a basic query object to the aggregate function and have it work correctly? Or is there a library that can parse the JSON for aggregations into the appropriate spring mongo template aggregation object?